# ArrayList.get(i) gives an unreliable result

Tags: java

I wrote the following bit of code to determine if two same sized arrays are identical:

```
retVal = true;
for (int i = 0; i < array1.size(); i++) {
    if (array1.get(i) != array2.get(i)){ 
    retVal = false;
    break;
 }
}
```

In some unexplained cases the if statement returned true, though it wasn't (checked in debugger). In others it gave the right result.
I fixed it by doing the following trivial fix:

```
int val1, val2;
retVal = true;
for (int i = 0; i < array1.size(); i++) {
   val1 = array1.get(i);
   val2 = array2.get(i);
   if (val1 != val2) {
       retVal = false;
       break;
   }
}
```

Any Idea what could be the reason?

Comment: What's the *type* of the two arrays

Comment: Don't use `!=` or `==` to compare Objects!!!!

Comment: The type is irrelevant. If this is arraylist, then the type is some class which extends Objects. Thus it is safer to compare them using .equals :)

Comment: Why not use [equals on the ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) instead?

Comment: They are ArrayList<Integer>

Comment: @OP - see "Edit:" in my answer -- downvoted or not, that's probably the answer.

Answer (score 2):

What are your arrays holding? `String`s?

If so, then  you can't do in Java `==` to compare strings. You need to use `equals` method.

So your comparison will become:

```
if (array1.get(i).equals(array2.get(i)))
```

If they're holding other type of objects, then you need to make sure how `equals` method in those objects is defined.

Comment: As above: ArrayList<Integer>. I'm comparing an Integer to an Integer.

Comment: I guess I should have used intValue().  Thanks

Comment: Actually you should rather assume to have a generic list and use the `equals` method of the elements.

Comment: using intValue is same as what you are doing in second case. Instead of finding ways for unboxing its better to call equals();

Answer (score 0):

We don't know what you're comparing, but it isn't the same thing in both cases.

ArrayLists cannot hold ints, so the first one is using != to compare two things that aren't ints.  In the second case, the code is autoboxing whatever is there to int, and you're comparing the results of that.

Is this a trick question of some sort?

edit: I suppose the ArrayList could be holding Integers, and in the first case you are testing whether the locations hold the same Integer objects, and in the second whether they hold the same integer value.  But we don't know how you declare the ArrayLists, though it would only take you two more lines to show us that.

Comment: Thanks all. I understand my mistake. Strange that in some cases it worked and in others not.

Comment: So what was the mistake?  If this answer provided it, it is customary to mark it as the answer.  If there is something else, you could tell us so that all could learn.

Comment: @user.... Normally Integers from -128 to 127 (or so) are cached, so it will magically work if all values checked are from that range.

Comment: Sorry. The mistake was the I used array1.get(i) != array2.get(i) instead of (!array1.equals(array2)) or if I had done an element wise comparison using array1.get(i).intValue()

Answer (score 0):

Nothing strange about the behavior. it's entirely dependent on the input elements in arraylist in your case.

usually we depend on autoboxing while inserting Wrapper objects in a collection.

when you do `list.add(1);` or `Integer i =1;`, autoboxing is done using Integer.valueOf() which uses a cache of Integer range from -127 to 128 (inclusively), i.e. same object reference is returned for same int value in this range.

```
            Integer a = 2;
            Integer b = 2;      
            System.out.println(a==b); 
           // true as referring same object and not because they have same value

            //for values outside range -127 to 128
            a=200;
            b=200;          

            System.out.println(a==b);
           //false as the two references are pointing different objects now


            System.out.println(a.equals(b));
            //returns true as values are compared
            //same as a.intValue() == b.intValue();
```

Thus your code might work correctly for a range but fail outside it with != (as array1.get(i) will return Integer reference and if condition will check for referential equality )
Therefore always prefer equals() for comparing values with Object References.

> second case works as the Integers are implicitly unboxed and != does a
>   value check with primitives.

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

> *I wrote the following bit of code to determine if two same sized*
>   *arrays are identical*

**Ignorantia APIs neminem excusat**

You're actually comparing two lists. Beside the usual `==` vs. `.equals()` confusion error, you should read the API (of `ArrayList`) where the following is of most interest to you:

> `public boolean equals(Object o)`
>
> Compares the specified object with this list for equality. **Returns**
>   **true if and only if the specified object is also a list, both lists**
>   **have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two**
>   **lists are equal. (Two elements e1 and e2 are equal if (e1==null ?**
>   **e2==null : e1.equals(e2)).) In other words, two lists are defined to**
>   **be equal if they contain the same elements in the same order.**
>
> This implementation first checks if the specified object is this list.
>   If so, it returns true; if not, it checks if the specified object is a
>   list. If not, it returns false; if so, it iterates over both lists,
>   comparing corresponding pairs of elements. If any comparison returns
>   false, this method returns false. If either iterator runs out of
>   elements before the other it returns false (as the lists are of
>   unequal length); otherwise it returns true when the iterations
>   complete.

So just do: `list1.equals(list2)` and shine on.